# Using Entrypoint with arguments to decide which .dll to run

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am experimenting with Docker and using arguments to decide what code in the image should start.

I have these two entrypoints which both work if run by themselves.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MultiStart.API.dll"]
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MultiStart.Worker1.dll"]
```

I would like to decide which one is run by using arguments when i call `docker run`

I've tried several things along the lines of

```
CMD ["dotnet", $start]
ENTRYPOINT ./dotnet $start
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", $start]
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet" $start]
```

and then calling it using something like this.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -e start=MultiStart.API.dll --name multi multistart
```

But no matter what I do I end up with this error (or some variant there of):

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./dotnet: not found
```

Any suggestions as to how this can be achieved?

---

Ill include the entire Dockerfile that will start one of the two processes for clarity.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src", "src"]
COPY ["*.sln", ""]

RUN dotnet restore "src/MultiStart.API/MultiStart.API.csproj"
RUN dotnet restore "src/MultiStart.Worker1/MultiStart.Worker1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src"
RUN dotnet build "MultiStart.API/MultiStart.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
RUN dotnet build "MultiStart.Worker1/MultiStart.Worker1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MultiStart.API/MultiStart.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
RUN dotnet publish "MultiStart.Worker1/MultiStart.Worker1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

# both of these work by themselves.
#ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MultiStart.API.dll"]  
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MultiStart.Worker1.dll"]
```

Comment: try `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet"]` and `docker run imagename dllname`? and try `ARG` keyword to specify variable if you prefer your way.  [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

Comment: This worked great, please post this as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker run` cannot pass variable like that, after all, docker file is not bash script.
The simplist way is

*dockerfile*

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["command"]
```

*docker run*

```sh
docker run imagename argument list
```

If you want to declare variables in docker file, you can use [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) or [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables).